# Adding a class to a label with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to a label of a checkbox on the click event of the checkbox with jQuery.  I am calling the following function after retrieving the HTML for the checkboxes in an ajax call.

```
function modDispTable() {
    $("#disptbl :input").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var lblid = $(this).attr("id") + "_lbl";

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(lblid).addClass('chksel');
            }
            else {
                $(lblid).removeClass('chksel');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

There are more checkboxes, but the resulting HTML for all of the checkboxes looks similar to this:

```
<label id="chk_sobomnifeat_lbl" name="chk_sobomnifeat_lbl" for="chk_sobomnifeat" class="radiolbl chkmod chkmod1">
<input id="chk_sobomnifeat" name="chk_sobomnifeat" value="chk" type="checkbox">
Sobella Omni Feature Display
</label>
```

Right now, all that I am trying to do is apply a different background color.  The CSS is in a file that is included with the page.

```
.chksel {
    background-color: #D3CEBE;
}
```

I am not getting any errors.  Debugging in Firebug has me even more baffled as the click events are triggered, `lblid` contains the correct id value (the label's), and the `addClass` line is supposedly executed.

Does anyone have any ideas why the class will not apply?  I am using JQuery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing a `#` in your ID string.

`var lblid = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_lbl";`

Comment: I had to pick one pointing out this little facepalm moment of mine... Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

You probably need the id selector like:

```
var lblid = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_lbl";
```

But even cooler woud be (since you are using the proper markup already):

```
var label = $("[for=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]");
```

Comment: Interesting... How would I use `label` in my script?  I may be missing what you are going for here.  After assigning `label`, would I do something like `label.addClass("chksel");`?

Comment: I did a little research and figured out what you were going for here.  I absolutely loved it!  It cut a bunch of code out of my particular situation.  I used this as a guide - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input/285565#285565.  Thanks a bunch!  It was way cooler!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The neat thing about that solution is, that you don't need a bunch of unnecessary ids. You can use label as a jQuery object and also wrap it into $(label) (using a jQuery object on a jQuery object will return that object).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "#":

```
var lblid = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_lbl";
```

Answer (score 1):

change the selector to `$('#'+lblid)`