# Obtain the label name using javascript

Tags: javascript, label

I want to know whether it is possible to obtain the label name along the text box.
For example, the following code asks the user for their name and "Your name" is the label.

```
<label>Your name:</label> <input type="text" size="15" name="name" />
```

I want to know if I can obtain the label name "Your Name" using javascript.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, it'll be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on the first approach is clever:

[Find html label associated with a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input)

Otherwise use a toolkit and lots of clumsy DOM traversal.

Comment: what if its not a label; since not all websites have label but its something like    

        <input type = "text" size="15">YOUR NAME</input>
How do I obtain "YOUR NAME" from this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Method**

`document.getElementById('<%=Label.ClientID%>').value`

**JQuery Method**

```
$('#<%= Label.ClientID %>').val()
```