# Disable jQueryUI button and keep its original layout/style

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-button

If I disable jQueryUI button using "disabled" option, button goes dim.
But I don't want it that way - I just want it unresponsive and styled in its original layout - no rollovers, no clicks - everything dead.

Unbinding button click from button doesn't help. 
Unbinding all events from button using unbind() just as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could override the JQueryUI CSS

Comment: @Bouillou: if you meant mybuttons.removeClass("ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled"), this could work but it will leave clicks. And maybe rollovers. I want the button dead, as written in my question.

Comment: Still trying to figure out why this was downvoted. I'm surprised this isn't a larger issue.

Comment: @SeanBeck, don't have a faintest idea. But the solution still works for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you could just remove the "disabled" classes after disabling the button:

```
$( "button" ).button();

$( "button" ).button('disable');

$( "button" ).removeClass('ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled')
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9gq9n/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, at last I figured it out.
To disable any jQueryUI button, including 'buttonized' checkbox with label attached (while retaining its original layout), you have to do the following:

- unbind its events
- unbind events from its label(s)

So, here's an example:

```
$("mybuttons").unbind();
$("mybuttons").getLabels().unbind();
```

I'm using a plugin I recently wrote ([originally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input/13047684#13047684) by SO member [Gijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713326/gijs), but didn't work always...)

```
jQuery.fn.getLabels = function () {
    return this.map(function () {
        var parentLabels = $(this).parents('label').get();
        var associatedLabels = this.id ? associatedLabels = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").get() : [];
        return parentLabels.concat(associatedLabels);
    });
};
```

Hope it helps.