# Javascript: Cannot convert document.getElementById(fieldname).label to object

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find html label associated with a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input)

I have following html code -

```
        <label for='useremail'>Registered email address</label>
        <input type='text' value='' name='useremail' onfocus='hideLabel("useremail");' id='useremail' class='useremail'>
```

in my webpage and below code in Javascript

```
function hideLabel (fieldname) {
document.getElementById(fieldname).label.style.visibility = 'hidden'; }
```

My intent is to hide label when user clicks on the input field. When I am testing this, I am getting following error. Is something wrong with my code?

```
Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById(fieldname).label' to object
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).label is undefined`. What makes you think that the `input` DOM element has a `label` property?

Comment: There is an html5 property `labels` which gives a list of label elements associated with the input element. I'm not sure about support though.

Comment: @Musa: It does not seem to be supported by Firefox right now.

Comment: My mistake. I think I should use code snippet at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input before using .label function. You all are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of the `.label` - I found this SO question about creating it: [Find html label associated with a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input)

Incidentally, if you include that solution in your script it will work.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6J4M/) showing it in action.

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript to:

```
document.getElementById(fieldname).style.visibility = 'hidden'
```

NO need to put name label. After you change that give your label and id="useremail"

```
<label id='useremail'>Registered email address</label>
```