# Javascript: get radiobutton label with a specific "for" in label

Tags: javascript, input, label

I have a form element like this:

```
<div id="myformelement">
   <input type="radio" id="option1">
   <label for="option2">Option 1</label>
   <input type="radio" id="option2">
   <label for="option2">Option 2</label> 
   <input type="radio" id="option3">
   <label for="option3">Option 3</label> 
   <input type="radio" id="option4">
   <label for="option4">Option 4</label>  
</div>
```

I want to hide the input fields "option2" and "option3" and their labels.

I can hide the input bullets by addressing the id. Unfortunately the corresponding labels to the input fields only have a "for" tag with the id in it.

How can I do this with javascript (no jquery).

I found this question ([Find html label associated with a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input)), but this seems only to work with one label within an ID, I can not use this.

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,
Malte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do it with `nextSibling`:

```
var rdo = document.getElementById("option2");
var lbl;

rdo.style.display = "none";
for (lbl = rdo.nextSibling; lbl && lbl.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "LABEL"; lbl = lbl.nextSibling) {
}
if (lbl) {
    lbl.style.display = "none";
}
```

But I have a better option for you: It seems to be a well-kept secret that `label` elements can *contain* the `input` they relate to, and when they do no `for` is required at all. So if you change your HTML to:

```
<div id="myformelement">
   <label><input type="radio" id="option1"> Option 1</label>
   <label><input type="radio" id="option2"> Option 2</label> 
   <label><input type="radio" id="option3"> Option 3</label> 
   <label><input type="radio" id="option4"> Option 4</label>  
</div>
```

...it gets a *lot* easier:

```
document.getElementById("option2").parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

You just find the `input`, traverse up to its parent which is the `label`, and hide that (which will hide the `input` as well).

Comment: +1 Inputs in labels may solve the problem in better way than hiding elements separately.

Answer (score 4):

In pure JavaScript you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector):

```
document.querySelector("label[for='option2']").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely, provided you don't need to support IE7 or earlier. http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Who cares about IE7 and earlier ;)

Comment: @ VisioN: Really quite a large number of people in Asia, particularly China. But hey, we can all safely ignore twenty some-odd percent of 1.3 billion people, right? ;-) (Speaking seriously: Quite a few sites can [certainly all of the ones I've been involved with], if they're only in English. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess forcing people to be updated is never bad :)

Comment: I agreed, convincing people to use modern browsers ist high priority. Anyway, this solution also worked