# JQuery "onchange" event on just one checkbox among multiple in a group based on label text

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I have a group of checkboxes as -

```
<input id="check_1" name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_1">One</label>&nbsp;

<input id="check_2" name="check[2]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_2">Two</label>&nbsp;

<input id="check_3" name="check[3]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_3">Three</label>
```

Due to variable values of `id` and `name`, I'm unable to handle onclick event on checkbox with label `One`.

I've tried this which works fine, but I don't want to use `check_1` since the number 1 is variable and could be changed.

```
$("#check_1").change(function() {
  alert('Checkbox One is clicked');
});
```

How do I do this as I have no access to modify the html ?

Comment: use `this` keyword

Comment: try `$('input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: `$("input[id^='check_']").change()`

Comment: @philantrovert In that case how will I check the next label is one which is being checked ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit us `this` inside the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find html label associated with a given input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input)

Comment: You can check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a selector like this `$('input[type="checkbox"]:has(+ label:contains("One"))')` with the label text as below,

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]:has(+ label:contains("One"))').on('click', function(){
  alert('Checkbox One is clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check_1" name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_1">One</label>&nbsp;

<input id="check_2" name="check[2]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_2">Two</label>&nbsp;

<input id="check_3" name="check[3]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_3">Three</label>
```

Comment: This works fine, is there any cleaner way ? will accept this if I don't find any +1

Comment: If you want to find the checkbox by the label text then this is the cleaner `jquery` way of selector. If you need to find by any other logic, please let me know and I will update the answer

Comment: @jitendrapurohit Performance wise its good as this is using the single selector rather than manipulating the `dom` with multiple selectors

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your only criteria is the text of the `label` so you could target the input  based on that label like :

```js
$('label:contains("One")').prev('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    console.log('One changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check_1" name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_1">One</label>&nbsp;

<input id="check_2" name="check[2]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_2">Two</label>&nbsp;

<input id="check_3" name="check[3]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label for="check_3">Three</label>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to fire the alert event on Two and Three option check

Comment: You could do that based on the label text, check my update.

Comment: Working, Thanks +1. But this doesn't make sure the click input is a checkbox :(