# How to get previous DOM element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using javascript to access previous element's attribute value.

**My HTML :**

```html
  <form>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name :</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">E-Mail :</label>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </div>
   </form>
```

I use loop to read all input elements in my form.

But, i want to read the label's HTML.

**ex.**

```
  Input Element : 'email'

  Label         : 'E-Mail'
```

Also i want **Javascript** Solution ONLY !

//////// I'm not using jQuery ! ///////

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: you should show us what you have tried. Show your JS.

Comment: "document.getElementsByName("email").previousElementSibling.innerHTML"

Comment: 'Previous' doesn't have too much sense, in this case, you need inputs and their labels, right? :)

Comment: Yah... Only Previous or clup with label "For" attribte.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan: `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements. Which one in the collection do you want? If more than one, use a loop. If only one, then grab it by index `[0]`. The `.previousElementSibling` property is correct if used directly on an element.

Comment: Where and when you need to access `label`? `for` attributes should have unique values, why not to use that? Like `document.querySelector('label[for="email"]')`.

Comment: @squint Its for complete form. I'm just give sample data.

Comment: @Teemu Actually i implement simple validation library, so i need to send back the response to label. That's why i need label access.

Comment: So, you need the label for the current input at hands in the loop? I'd still go with `querySelector`, since it's possible that there's element(s) between the label and input. You'd get a proper answer, if you could show an exact use case, currently we've to guess too much.

Comment: Its not duplicate. Just read it fully. I need previous "different DOM" element. Not same ...

Comment: One more thing, `label`'s `for` attribute refers to `id` of the input element, not `name`. It is also possible to write a working label construction without `for` attribute, like so: `<label>Email: <input name="email"></label>`. Just some observes, since you're creating a library, and can't control the markup in the form to validate.

Comment: Why do you need the label text? What are you planning to do with it? Is your problem to get the previous element, or to get the associated label wherever it is?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use [`labels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) property of an input to get the correct label elements of a specific input element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.previousElementSibling` property to get the label element.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i =0; i< el.length;i++){
console.log(el[i]);
console.log(el[i].previousElementSibling);
if(el[i].getAttribute("name")==el[i].previousElementSibling.getAttribute("for")){
console.log("it is label");
}
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mwaodeg/2/) example.

Comment: Simple i get access of label.
But, is it will may distracted by some other elements right ??
Any Feasible solution for access only label ?

Comment: Considering the code is in a library, what guarantees the previous element being `label` here?

Comment: Knowing that only label has the attribute `for` and this attribute is equal to name of the input you can use `if(el[i].getAttribute("name")==el[i].previousElementSibling.getAttribute("for")){//code here}`.

Answer (score 1):

Used the code here:[Find html label associated with a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input)

```
//associate all labels to inputs:
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL'); for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) { if (labels[i].htmlFor != '') { var elem = document.getElementsByName(labels[i].htmlFor)[0]; if (elem) elem.label = labels[i]; } }

 //get email for example
 email=document.getElementsByName("email")[0];
EmailLabelvalue=email.label.innerHTML;
```

It connects every label with its Input, than you can easily get it using input.label. To get its containing value use .innerHTML ...

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("email")` this will not pick .. label.

Comment: It will get the email element, just an example how to use...

Comment: Generate : "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' "

Comment: I simply took the code from the other answer, didnt checked if it work. Edited...