# Edit form field labels in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular

I have a built a model-driven (reactive) form, as shown [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html), in Angular 2.

My html looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value, userForm.valid)">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" id="firstName" required>

    <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastname" id="lastName" required>

    <br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" formControlName="email" id="email">

    <br>
</form>
```

In my .ts file:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...

ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.required],
        lastname: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['',],


    })

    this.userForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);           
    });
}
```

I've added the `required` attribute in my template as well, as suggested by [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#reactive)

Quoting:

> required remains, not for validation purposes (we'll cover that in the code), but rather for css styling and accessibility.

**What I want is to cycle through each form field and add a `*` to the associated label if the field is `required`.**

So, `First Name` reads `First Name *`; and so on.

How would I go about doing that. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "if the field is required"? Do you still want or plan to keep the `required` attribute, or should it be removed?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I still plan to keep the attribute. I just want the labels to be updated. Basically, If I have 10 fields and 8 are required, I want those 8 fields' labels to be edited automatically, rather than having to manually add/remove the asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[required]'
})
export class LabelRequiredDirective {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef){}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.labels.forEach(l => l.textContent += ' *');
  }
}
```

Because the selector matches every element that has the `required` attribute, it is applied to all elements where the label should be updated.

Sadly `nativeElement.labels` is only supported in Chrome. For other browsers another strategy is necessary to get the label associated with an input element (See also [Find html label associated with a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input))

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. I've created a new file, put the code in it; included it in my app.module declarations. Since there is no custom name involved, I haven't edited my form template. Do I need to? (Btw, I fixed some TS errors I was getting by saying `export class LabelRequiredDirective` and `this.elRef.nativeElement`. I hope that was okay.)

Comment: Sounds fine. Have you checked if the constructor and `ngAfterContentInit` are called?

Comment: Yes, they're being called. `this.elRef.nativeElement` returns the element as expected; but the labels array is empty. I'm checking in the latest chrome. Anyway, I get the gist now. I can take it from here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Works for me https://plnkr.co/edit/CeuUpAxjzT1lAFiU829L?p=preview. `for="lastname"` didn't work, because `id="lastName"` differs in uppercase `N`. It adds `&nbsp;*` though. Didn't spend too much time in reasoning about that. You could also just add a CSS class using `@HostBinding('class.required') isRequired = true; and add the `*` using CSS (for example using content).

Comment: Cool. Thanks again.