# How to get <label for> value Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I have some check boxes in my HTML page. And also each component have  attribute. I need to get the  value if the check box is checked.

Following is my HTML code

```html
<div class="col-6 col-12-small">
    <h4>Document Submited</h4>
 <input type="checkbox" id="idcopy" name="checkbox">
 <label for="idcopy">NIC Copy</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="birthcertificate" name="checkbox">
 <label for="birthcertificate">Birth Certificate</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="nomineeNic" name="checkbox">
 <label for="nomineeNic">Nominee NIC copy</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="checkbox">
 <label for="agreement">Agreement</label>
</div>
```

I already tried to get the text by using document.getElementById(idcopy).text()

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061155/43452)

Answer (score 3):

You call get all element attribute by `attr(name)` ....

```js
$(':checkbox').on('click',function() {
  if(this.checked) {
  console.log($(this).next('label').attr('for'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6 col-12-small">
    <h4>Document Submited</h4>
 <input type="checkbox" id="idcopy" name="checkbox">
 <label for="idcopy">NIC Copy</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="birthcertificate" name="checkbox">
 <label for="birthcertificate">Birth Certificate</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="nomineeNic" name="checkbox">
 <label for="nomineeNic">Nominee NIC copy</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="checkbox">
 <label for="agreement">Agreement</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get all input fields
const allInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));

// Whenever any input field change
const handleInputChange = e => {
  
  // Create a values array for each checked input
  const values = allInputs.reduce((acc, input) =>
  
    // If field is checked
    input.checked
    
      // Add its label content to values array
      ? [...acc, document.querySelector(`label[for="${input.id}"]`).textContent]
      
      // Or return return previous array
      : acc, []);

  console.log(values);
};

// Bind event on all input fields
allInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleInputChange));
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-12-small">
    <h4>Document Submited</h4>
 <input type="checkbox" id="idcopy" name="checkbox">
 <label for="idcopy">NIC Copy</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="birthcertificate" name="checkbox">
 <label for="birthcertificate">Birth Certificate</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="nomineeNic" name="checkbox">
 <label for="nomineeNic">Nominee NIC copy</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="checkbox">
 <label for="agreement">Agreement</label>
</div>
```

You may also have reusable function like:

```js
const getLabel = (labelFor, rootElement = document) =>
  rootElement.querySelector(`label[for="${labelFor}"]`);

// Or to get text content directly:
const getLabel = (labelFor, rootElement = document) =>
  (rootElement.querySelector(`label[for="${labelFor}"]`) || {}).textContent;

// Boolean || is there to avoid throwing error when no matching label found in DOM
```

*Although, for simpler code you may put the data you want to get from checkboxes either directly in checkbox attribute (like: `<input type="checkbox" id="myId" data-myCustomData="My data if box is checked" />`), or in a JS object:*

```js
const myData = {
  checkboxId1: "Data for first checkbox foo",
  checkboxId5: "Data for first checkbox bar",
};
```