# Need to get data out of an HTML form using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get some simple data out a form on a webpage. Should be pretty simple, but one, I can't use jQuery, it has to be plain JS, and two, it's on a legacy system so it has to work in IE11 only.

Here is an image of the form fields I'm working with:

[image]

I need to get the ID of the label and the value of the field as indicated in the red boxes. This is how they're mapping this to the DB. I have to pull these on the form, then put them in a spreadsheet.

The most simple way I've tried to do this is using:

```
document.getElementById('Section1_0').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Of course this is kind of overkill since then I get back EVERY node in the DOM and then I would have to parse that out using something like `JSON.parse()` or something similar.

In short, if there is an easier way to get just the IDs and the values, that would be great. If I have to create an array and then iterate over that to pull the Ids and values I can do that as well. I've tried a few things, and I'm banging my head against the wall because the structure of the form isn't consistent.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285522/find-html-label-associated-with-a-given-input/8913025

Comment: there are no form inputs shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```js
const labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
Array.from(labels).forEach(label => {
    const labelText = label.innerHTML;
    const labelId = label.getAttribute('id');
   console.log(labelText);
   console.log(labelId);
});
```

```html
<label id="label_id_1">Lable 1</label><br>
<label id="label_id_2">Lable 2</label><br>
<label id="label_id_3">Lable 3</label><br>
<label id="label_id_4">Lable 4</label><br>
<label id="label_id_5">Lable 5</label><br>
```